# Origin of Fredholm operators

Tags: functional-analysis

It is known that the notion of Fredholm operator, without using this name, was introduced by F.Noether in 1921. Can anone say, who and when proposed to call these operators Fredholm? For a certain time  the name 'Noether operator' was also used. Who and where  proposed to use this name?